# Bower install doesn't seem to be working (Windows 7) - not getting bower_components directory, grunt serve cannot find bower packages

Tags: windows-7, yeoman, bower, bower-install

I'm having problems getting `bower install` working.  I'm running through a `yo webapp` generator which does scaffolds out for me.

In my `bower.json` file, it give me two dependencies:

```
{
    "name": "webapp-test",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "~1.11.1",
        "modernizr": "~2.8.2"
    }
}
```

When I run a `bower install` after the generator, I would think it would be pulling down all dependencies with that command.  I have to run it 2x to get both dependencies. This seems wrong to me, why is not grabbing all dependencies with the first command?

I then try to run `grunt serve` but that is failing, stating **cannot find where you keep your bower packages**.

In my webapp structure, I do **not** have a `bower_components` directory. Shouldn't the `bower install` command be giving me that?

[image]
Any ideas why my `bower install` and `grunt serve` commands don't seem to be working?

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: you could add the .bowerrc in the same directory with bower.json to specify which directory it should put it , if you want  it to put in specific directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right there in the command shell, the system can not find git. The best bet is to install either MSysGit or Github for Windows.

Comment: I have git installed, I use that via the git bash.  Should I be running yeoman via the git bash instead of the command prompt?  I typically use cygwin instead of the command prompt, but that doesn't work with node/yeoman.

Comment: Yes, try the git bash shell. Alternatively, if you install Github For Windows, it adds an icon that will open up either cmd or powershell with Git on the path.

Comment: Perfect, ran what I did above via the git bash and it's all working.  Looks like I'll be using the git bash for all yeoman flows, thanks much!